# How do I minimize the cost from errors?

Tags: bayesian, classification, bayes-optimal-classifier

Bayes' Optimal Classifier is known to achieve the minimum error rate for a dataset $x_1, \ldots, x_n, x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Suppose that each error had a cost associated with it. For example, in a binary classifier, classifying $y_i = 1$ when $y_i = 0$ would have a cost $\alpha$ and classifying the other way would have a cost $\beta$.

If $\alpha = \beta$, it is known that making decisions based on Bayes' Optimal Classifier also achieves the minimum **cost**. However, what if $\alpha \neq \beta$, i.e., different kinds of errors have different kinds of costs? In machine learning, how is making predictions so as to minimize cost achieved? Is it a kind of least squares?

Comment: Have you thought about bayesian decision theory? This gives us a coherent mathematical framework for making decisions under uncertainty and it driven by assigning costs (called "utilities") to events